# Xcode C++ Header Files Directory

Tags: c++, xcode

I've been trawling the internet to no avail while trying to find an answer to where Xcode stores its C++ header (.h) files like "stdio.h" etc. I'm looking for the directory just out of curiousity.

Thanks in advance!
Harry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Standard library headers are spread across two primary locations, one of them highly dependent on the SDK choice you have for your project.

For the regular C standard headers, you'll find them in the following location, assuming a regular install of Xcode:

```
/Applications
  /Xcode.app
    /Contents
      /Developer 
        /Platforms 
          /*ChosenTargetPlatform*
            /Developer
              /SDKs
                /*ChosenMacOSSDK*
                  /usr
                    /include
```

where `ChosenTargetPlatform` is one of :

```
iPhoneOS.platform
iPhoneSimulator.platform
MacOSX.platform
```

and the `ChosenMasOSSDK` is from whichever SDKs you have installed on your build rig and have chosen as the target OS. For example:

- `MacOS10.9.sdk` is for Mavericks
- `MacOS10.10.sdk` is for Yosemite

etc...

---

The C++ standard library headers are a little different. They're stored independent of the MacOS SDK and target platform. The default location, again assuming you have a stock, run of the mill install:

```
/Applications
  /Xcode.app
    /Contents
      /Developer
        /Toolchains
          /XcodeDefault.xctoolchain
            /usr
              /include
                /c++
                  /v1
```

The reason behind this (as near as I can see) is the C++ standard library is coupled together *with* the formal toolchain itself. I.e. clang, c99, c11, etc, are all part of the formal toolchain including the headers *and* any required libs, executables, etc.

Most of this you can explore for yourself by doing the follow:

- In a source file hover over the filename portion of a `#include<filename>`
- Cmd-click the filename, it should open.
- From the File menu, select "Show in Finder"

That should open a Finder windows and allow you to explore the file's location. If you include the `Path` button as one of the toolbar options in your Finder configuration it will reveal the full path of where you are.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

For xCode 6 you can find that file here:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h